# Can a USB drive's serial number or unique hardware be used to identify me?

Tags: tails, deanonymization

When using a technology like tails, For privacy concerns, should I concern myself with whether a USB drive, and my purchase of it, can be used to trace me while running tails?

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically - **YES**, if it will be a way to make a hardware listing query like `lsusb -v`